# SQL: Still has duplicate record after Group By statement

Tags: sql

I worked with Suppliers table in [w3cSchool](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all), and I run below SQL statement:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(Country) AS count_times 
FROM Suppliers 
GROUP BY Country 
HAVING count_times = 1
```

It should returns the countries that only has 1 supplier, but instead it returns two 'Sweden' in the result.

I should be a simple problem, however I cannot find it after checking the table data around. Appreciate for any hints.

Result:

```
Country   count_times
----------------------
Brazil          1
Denmark         1
Finland         1
Netherlands     1
Norway          1
Singapore       1
Spain           1
Sweden          1
Sweden          1
```

Comment: `having count(Country)  = 1` (The column alias is created after the having clause is evaluated.)

Comment: @jarlh, it is not working. Interesting thing is that even I remove `having count...` constraint, it still returns two `Sweden`.

Comment: @jarlh Eh? What's that?

Comment: Yep, the data is corrupt.

Comment: `HAVING count_times = 1` is no Standard SQL, your query returns an error message, when you run it in w3schools. What's the DBMS you using, MySQL?

Comment: @dnoeth, Oh! you get error msg. I didn't get error message when I run this query in w3Schools. Well, since it is online environment of w3Schools, I think we should get the same result.

Comment: @Strawberry, what is what?

Comment: I tried it online (in Firefox) and it failed, when I used the WebSQL (in Chrome, not supported in Firefox) it returned your result. Online there's no trailing blank in Sweden, but in WebSQL. I don't know what's the DBMS behind WebSQL, but it's definitely not following Standard SQL (`HAVING count_times = 1` is invalid and trailing spaces should be ignored)

Comment: @jarlh count_times works fine for me (with an uncorrupted data set)

Comment: @dnoeth, I cannot explain that. But I could tell you that I'm using Macbook with Mac OSX and Chrome without error here:)

Comment: There are two different DBMSes behind w3schools. E.g. the Online version uses `+` for string concat and fails for `HAVING count_times = 1` while WebSQL uses Standard SQL `||` and works.

Comment: MacBook here, too

Comment: @Strawberry, may work with some dbms products. (OP hasn't told us which dbms it is. ANSI SQL do not allow column aliases in the HAVING clause.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2 "Sweden" may not the same, such as one has blanks in the tail, like "Sweden   ". You may select distinct Country to validate.

Comment: Yeah, `distinct` will return two `Sweden`, lovely...So the problem is in the original data source instead of the query statement.

Comment: @ChuckZHB: Well, trailing blanks should not cause any problem, when your DBMS works according to Standard SQL which ignores trailing spaces

Comment: The data is corrupt. The question is closed.

Answer (score 0):

I think problem is with there dataset it seems that In Sweden a space or special characters is present in the end, so if you search using below query you will get two records:

```
select * from Suppliers WHERE lower(COUNTRY) like 'sweden%';
```

Below query will give you correct result:

```
SELECT Country, COUNT(Country) AS count_times 
FROM Suppliers 
GROUP BY trim(Country)
HAVING COUNT(Country) = 1;
```

Comment: This query will lose many countries in result, it is not worked well. But the idea is correct, `sweden` is different in source table data of DB.

Answer (score 0):

The **group by** is applied on all the data in column but some  are missing right
so the question is
**when does group by doesn't group by the data?**
for example

```
   Sweden  1
   Sweden  1
```

treated differently

try this query and

```
   update Suppliers set Country = 'Sweden' where SupplierID in (9,17);
```

then apply your query

```
   SELECT Country, count(Country) as count_times FROM Suppliers 
   group by Country 
   having count_times = 1
```

your query has no issues but the data in the column has. That's why group by is not applied